# How to obtain the correct photos for a given location?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Google photos api doesn't seem to be able to get accurate images for given places, I am also interested to see if there any other valid api that gives good images based on the geo location?

For example the following two address that are 15 kms apart give the same image from google maps API (which is [this image](https://github.com/rohitmanglik/scrap-preprocessor/raw/master/output/image_PTC%20Aviation%20Academy.jpg)) but both of them can give different image as per their google maps link. How can we obtain the photos of a location? I am fine to obtain the image of a place even with any other API but I couldn't find any api to give the correct image of a given location.

**1) Address :** "PTC Aviation Academy, No. 16/29, 1st Main Road,Chromepet,Chennai-600044"

**Photo identifier :** u'CoQBdwAAAL3wZ4ivkXxROmI8ACqmW6wUIo6rKcWWeevH3j8ZwrWG0UbYRThYdUna8T8lzgfi0p_e1d3OGT2S0DPpJDZF1PyuHFlulAiy6pDDqmMd4bJpMdD8UhIZlFpRMYGJe-IJHk5VSqYUdwd4rimhtVc7MNFw9F8MYTgjX5ul2RN-bZmdEhAOSOJ9BRjuLe3Yd8TThBt6GhRJL5s6YJQhSfi3IZeoiPXDKR4kcA'

**Google place link :** https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/PTC+Aviation+Academy/@12.951897,80.1371513,17z

**2) Address :**"IIT Madras, IIT P.O., Beside Adyar Cancer Institute, Opposite to C.L.R.I, Sardar Patel Road",Adyar,Chennai-600036."

**Photo identifier :** u'CoQBdwAAAH29SZFNcCr7zJHBmLkwWnBVWdE8y8nxtnxWjXwEcwwpyIQO-oZegCOnNehFtO7Q1ttCNS-bzy566AQ52NB-alf3hHt6K3RozswO_K0XnH3BI6C7A9j8nS_Zu7WwhLGKGM1gjyM_vVFrBeebAEPyDHLknezdYSMPw2jtPXbQ3r0bEhBgcOLLNyJ7Cw9kYKukLV4yGhTVXnor0fKc8pX47A5QV90eBsDzUA'

**Google place link :** https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/IIT+Madras/@13.0063336,80.2398367,17z

Comment: Did you Try Panoramio and Google Places API?

Comment: Also did you try grabbing that image using Selenium?

Comment: Can you please show me how you are calling the API - i mean "the code". I am really not sure whether "Google photos api" is of any use for you. It should be Google Maps I believe

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there is no street view imagery for these addresses. You can check it using Geocoder tool and dragging the pagman around:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D12.951897%252C80.13934

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D13.006334%252C80.242025

However, you can try to get images related to these places via Places API in two steps.

1. Execute a place search for a given address

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=PTC%20Aviation%20Academy%2C%20No.%2016%2F29%2C%201st%20Main%20Road%2CChromepet%2CChennai-600044&key=YOUR_API_KEY

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=IIT%20Madras%2C%20IIT%20P.O.%2C%20Beside%20Adyar%20Cancer%20Institute%2C%20Opposite%20to%20C.L.R.I%2C%20Sardar%20Patel%20Road%22%2CAdyar%2CChennai-600036&key=YOUR_API_KEY

2. The response from previous step will contain photos field with corresponding photo references. So you can use the photo reference in Places Photo requests

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?photoreference=CoQBcwAAABjgCEv2Y3kXzwo7BfsEVDDrApryPRxolGQGCVYictPKCvWQwbe8krHINggBVrEQA3OEf8EqbFHp0r98jrIJQ3F4awmIji7NOYI8MfsPK4leba2tRuWqbUr1dDZRW_hKDljRtewR50iOwd3F9MW5J4DIIwHSvCU41jqSqXyISpsEEhCol5Eq1OI0ne7i_2s_a9eRGhSTmK86GEeknPJXxecPu0KM_O4trA&maxwidth=600&key=YOUR_API_KEY

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?photoreference=CoQBdwAAAPp5qepynfTVao_XoW3QAMpul2rD7TrKosDA76-FPyhESJW4A5evjAHj8GWjvlcbc0ATDvEnsF7qHcNSFxkLZyscvJRY2e_DmCW2iLS0k6dJRSQVXOVOvrCe7yfwI-kOYIKbPgf8Gxk6yLfacUGESWuzRU30OMNne9yHwGJYakYNEhBR4f4jbHSx17cZoTm81IogGhSP3Vk9JPG-wVtpxgTeF27ZUmBkJg&maxwidth=600&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was looking for a way to fetch the photos available from google maps website. If you click [this link](https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/IIT+Madras/@13.0063336,80.2398367,17z), you can see some images on the top left near the name of the place. I expected those images to be available through google places API, is that not the case?

Comment: You can follow the same steps for this place: 1. Execute places text search; 2. Places text search will return a photos field with photo_reference. If you need all photos execute the places details search with place ID from the first request; 3. If you executed places details, peek up photo_reference from photos field in details response; 4. call places photos with corresponding photoreference.

Comment: I did those steps and the photo_reference if the photo identifier that I had added in my question. But it seems the issue is that it is not fetching the correct photos as I am able to see the correct photos in maps.google.com but not from the places API...